# Finding a complete URL based on known domain

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, findall

Using BeautifulSoup to pull a webpage based on a google search for a known domain such as .microsoft.com. I want to pull the entire URL including the 
"http(s)://" prefix.

I'm retrieving valid nodes, but I don't understand how to instruct the find_all method to include all the text left of the target text, inclusive of the first occurrernce of "http".

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3
import re

def make_soup(url):
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    r = http.request("GET", url)
    return BeautifulSoup(r.data,'lxml')

# to search 
query = "\"\.microsoft\.com\""
try:
    from googlesearch import search
    for j in search(query, tld="com", num=10, stop=1, pause=2): 
        #print(j)
        page = make_soup(j)

        for node in page.find_all(text=lambda x: x and ".microsoft.com" in x):
            print(node)
except ImportError:
    print("No module named 'google' found")
```

I'm receiving decent results that all end with ".microsoft.com", but I want the results to include the full URL, starting with the "http...microsoft.com"

Comment: I'm assuming you are searching for links, so you can do the following: First, get all the links in the page using `page.find_all('a')` then for each link try to find `link.get('href')` and search if `microsoft.com` is in it or not

Comment: By the way, where is the definition of the `search` function

Comment: No actually, I'm searching for a string in google - ".microsoft.com", then for each result, I'm going to the URL, and pulling the full URL that triggered the positive search result. So it could be "http://blahblahblah.microsoft.com" - but I want each of those URLs, from each of the google search URLs.

Comment: try: 
    from googlesearch import search 
except ImportError:  
    print("No module named 'google' found")

Comment: sorry, search code is above - had missed it from copy and paste

Comment: Then, I think to solve this problem, you only need to change your query from `"\"\.microsoft\.com\""` to `"\S+\"\.microsoft\.com\""` with adding `\S+` at the beginning. I hope this helps!

Comment: Your question is still not clear to me.

Comment: Adding the "\S+\" part just gives me this error for each result: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:858: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)"

Comment: @InfectedDrake I'm searching the web for occurrences of ".microsoft.com", so I get a list of URLs that google returns as having some form of "%.microsoft.com" within the webpage. I then want to request that URL and pull the full URL that has met my criteria of "wildcard.microsoft.com".

Comment: @MikeWalsh, the error has nothing to do with the query... it's an `insecure request`, try using a proxy when building the request.

Comment: Your first two paragraphs make no sense to me as an English text.

Comment: @MikeWalsh, I got your first part, but can you explain what you mean by "pull the full URL that has met my criteria"? The links in the Google search will include the full URL, why do you need to request that again?

Comment: @InfectedDrake I want to find all publicly exposed examples of URLs for Yahoo. Maybe someone's asked a question on a forum and exposed some internal server addresses. The structure might be "http://serverID.intra.yahoo.com". I want to search google for ".intra.yahoo.com". Then with the valid hits containing that exact string I want to request the HTML for each URL, parse it for ".intra.yahoo.com" and retrieve the prefixes, thus obtaining the full addresses - which could be "http://DC115.intra.yahoo.com", within someones stackoverflow/codeproject question. Does make better sense?